# access Django model in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm currently working on an app in which I want to automatically select the elements of two dropdown lists on selection of an element of another dropdown list :

[screnshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXIZY.png)

so if I select job 3, I'd like to automatically select qualification 3, and coefficient 3

I have this model to store the values that I want to change
:

```
class JobModel(models.Model):
    job = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    qualification = models.ForeignKey(Qualification, default=1, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    coefficient = models.ForeignKey(Coefficient, default=1, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

and this form :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered ">
    <thead class="thead">
        <tr>
            <th> REF</th>
            <th> poste</th>
            <th > nb </th>
            <th>{{ form.date_debut.label }}</th>
            <th>{{ form.date_fin.label }}</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>{{ form.poste_travail | add_class:'form_big'}} </td>
             <td>{{ form.metier_repere }}{{ form.qualification }} {{ form.coefficient }}</td>
             <td>{{ form.effectif | add_class:'form_small'}}</td>
             <td>{{ form.date_debut | add_class:'form_big'}}</td>
             <td>{{ form.date_fin | add_class:'form_big'}}</td>
         </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="calculer">

</form>
```

I found out that I needed tu use jQuery to achieve that but I don't know the first thing about it, so if anyone encountered a similar issue, or could help it would be super nice !

Comment: I think it's completely front issue. Check your dropdown list id and add jquery to select others when select job.

Comment: I'd recommend learning jQuery if you need to use it. No one will be able to give an answer/working example with jQuery to someone who have no clue how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at django-select2 it can be very handy for implementing dropdowns. https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/